# How do I convert a factor into date format?

Tags: r

I imported a CSV file with dates from a SQL query, but the dates are really date-time values and R doesn't seem to recognize them as dates:

```
> mydate
[1] 1/15/2006 0:00:00
2373 Levels: 1/1/2006 0:00:00 1/1/2007 0:00:00 1/1/2008 0:00:00 ... 9/9/2012 0:00:00
> class(mydate)
[1] "factor"
> as.Date(mydate)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How do I convert `mydate` to date format? (I don't need to include the time portion.)

Comment: First of all you probably want `as.POSIXct` since they're in datetime format.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You were close.  `format=` needs to be added to the `as.Date` call:

```
mydate <- factor("1/15/2006 0:00:00")
as.Date(mydate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
## [1] "2006-01-15"
```

Comment: Is there a base method for also taking hms into consideration?

Answer (score 12):

You can try lubridate package which makes life much easier

```
library(lubridate)

mdy_hms(mydate)
```

The above will change the date format to POSIXct

A sample working example:

```
> data <- "1/15/2006 01:15:00"
> library(lubridate)
> mydate <- mdy_hms(data)
> mydate
[1] "2006-01-15 01:15:00 UTC"
> class(mydate)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

**For case with factor use as.character**

```
data <- factor("1/15/2006 01:15:00")
library(lubridate)
mydate <- mdy_hms(as.character(data))
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the formats in `?strptime`

```
R> foo <-  factor("1/15/2006 0:00:00")
R> foo <- as.Date(foo, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")                                           
R> foo                                                                                       
 [1] "2006-01-15"                                                                             
R> class(foo)                                                                                
 [1] "Date"
```

Note that this will work even if `foo` starts out as a character. It will also work if using other date formats (`as.POSIXlt`, `as.POSIXct`).