# Slow String to Date Conversion Function

Tags: r

I wrote the following function to convert a vector of Strings to a vector of Dates (the code inside the for loop was inspired by this post: [R help converting factor to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496358/r-help-converting-factor-to-date)). When I pass in a vector of size 1000, this takes about 30 seconds. Not terribly slow, but I ultimately need to pass in about 100,000 so this could be a problem. Any ideas why this is slow and/or how to speed it up?

```
toDate <- function (dates) 
{
    theDates <- vector()
    for(i in 1:length(dates))
    {
        temp <- factor(dates[i])
        temp <- as.Date(temp, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
        theDates[i] <- temp
    }
 class(theDates) <- "Date"
 return(theDates)
}
```

Comment: reproducible example please? what's wrong with the answer given in the linked question, which is vectorized already???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The code works, it is just very slow so I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You are incurring 100,000 calls to `as.Date()`, one per iteration. That is silly when `as.Date()` is **already** vectorised and thus you could just do `as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` - you don't need to convert to a factor if they already are one and if not they will be character so doing that conversion to factor incurs further overhead.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks! It's running very fast now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

1. You don't need to loop over the `dates` vector as `as.Date()` can handle a vector of characters just fine in a single shot. Your function is incurring `length(dates)` calls to `as.Date()` plus some assignments to other functions, which all have overhead that is totally unnecessary.
2. You don't want to convert each individual date to a factor. You don't want to convert them at all (`as.Date()` will just convert them back to characters). If you did want to convert them, `factor()` is *also* vectorised, so you could (but you don't need this *at all, anywhere in your function*) remove the `factor()` line and insert `dates <- as.factor(dates)` *outside* the `for()` loop. But again, **you don't need to do this at all!**

Comment: and if you want it even faster see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786335/why-is-as-date-slow-on-a-character-vector