# How to convert factor data field to time field

Tags: r, time, casting, posixct

I have a R data frame like bellow,

```
Time      value
00:00:00      1
00:00:03      3
00:00:06      2
00:00:09      1
```

When I check the classes of fields in dataframe, i found that,

```
    Time     value
"factor" "integer"
```

Then I try to convert Time's data type into time using bellow code.

```
df["Time"] <- as.POSIXct(df["Time"],format="%H:%M:%S")
```

When I execute above code  below error was generated.

> Error in as.POSIXct.default(df["Time"], format = "%H:%M:%S") : 
>     do not know how to convert 'df["Time"]' to class “POSIXct”

My questions are, why is this error occurred and how I can over come this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496358/r-help-converting-factor-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that fails is because of the way you call the column `Time`. The easiest way to do it is to use the `$`, i.e.

```
as.POSIXct(df$Time,format="%H:%M:%S")
```

If however, you want to use brackets then you need to add 2 of them in order to extract it as a vector rather than as a data frame column, i.e.

```
as.POSIXct(df[["Time"]],format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Both of the above result to,

> ```
> [1] "2017-11-23 00:00:00 +03" "2017-11-23 00:00:03 +03" "2017-11-23 00:00:06 +03" "2017-11-23 00:00:09 +03"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
df["Time"] <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df["Time"]),format="%H:%M:%S")
```