# My ggplot graph showing 2018 first and then 2017 data. I want to reorder it

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: plot]

I have a data from Sept 2017 to August 2018.

But when I'm displaying it through ggplot, it plots from January 2018 to Aug 2018 and then Sept - Dec 2017. I want 2017 data first.

This is the code I've used:

```
ggplot(data = p3, 
       aes(x = month, 
           y = percentage)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = percentage*100), stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(y = percentage, label = formattable::percent(percentage)), 
            vjust = 1.5, colour="red")
```

Comment: I am guessing that `class(p3$month)` will return "factor". You need either to reorder the factor levels or format the column as a date.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496358/r-help-converting-factor-to-date

Comment: @neilfws how do I do it ? I'm new to R. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to transform the `month` column to a date by pre-pending "01/" to the front (*i.e.* the first day of each month).  Then you can use `scale_x_date`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

p3 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0("01/", month), "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, percentage)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    geom_text(aes(y = percentage, 
                  label = formattable::percent(percentage)), 
              vjust = 1.5, 
              colour = "red") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
                 date_labels = "%m/%Y")
```