# factor to date returns NA

Tags: r

I am sorry but I struggle with this:

```
mydate <- factor("2016-10-25")
as.Date(mydate, format = "%Y-%M-%D")
```

it returns NA. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try `as.Date(mydate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`. Some more info on the formats here: https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Comment: Similar answer here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496358/r-help-converting-factor-to-date

Comment: Look up format codes with `?strptime`.

Comment: um `as.Date(mydate)` works _just fine_ since that's the default ISO format it expects

Comment: Suggesting the use of `lubridate` for this example is crazy talk. It's the default ISO format and I don't think anyone rly wants to take **1250** microseconds to do the conversion (for _one_ element) when the built-in `as.Date()` does it in **30** microseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use small letters for month and day (`"%Y-%m-%d"`) instead of capital letters (`"%Y-%M-%D"`).

```
mydate <- factor("2016-10-25")
as.Date(mydate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

"2016-10-25"
```

[image]

Comment: well I tried this - I think but yes this works now. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to also add the output of `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(base = as.Date(mydate), lubr = lubridate::ymd(mydate))` to this answer to show the stark contrast to `lubridate` (also the `format` string is not necessary since it'll try the ISO format one by default)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lubridate` as follows:

```
    mydate <- factor("2016-10-25")
require(lubridate)
ymd(mydate)
```