# Transforming data.frame factor into date

Tags: r

I have been learning R through a series of videos on Google Developers youtube channel.

But I got stuck on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx_3zWo4sUs&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIK9qQfztXeybpHvru-TrqAP&index=9

Particularly the transformation of the factor into date. It always ends up as NA.

The code I tried is the same as in the video, and I also tried first translating it to char. But nothing works.

```
stocks <- read.delim("stocks.txt")

str(stocks)

summary(stocks)

head(stocks$date, 20)

txt.date <- as.character(stocks$date)
txt.date
head(txt.date, 10)

s.date <- as.Date(txt.date, "%d-%b-%y")
s.date

s.date <- as.Date(stocks$date, format = "%d-%b-%y")
s.date
```

The file stocks.txt is available at http://rfunction.com/archives/2859 if needed.

I expect I am just doing something stupid as I don't yet know the language, but I could use some help.

Comment: Hey, have you tried the solutions proposed here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496358/r-help-converting-factor-to-date

You may also specify your data types directly when using read.delim (?read.delim see colClasses). Or avoid creating factors by setting stringsAsFactors = FALSE in your read.delim call

Comment: this works for me : `stocks$date <- as.Date(stocks$date, "%d-%b-%y")`

Comment: @Arcoutte I have tried those solutions, except the one with the lubridate  package as there has got to be a way to do this w/o the package. I ran the code I pasted below and it didnt work

 mydate <- factor("20-Mar-13")
mydate
as.Date(mydate, format = "%d-%b-%y")

Comment: @RonakShah tried it, but they all went NA

Comment: What is your locale? `%b` is locale-dependent. If it is other than English you need to set it to English first for this to work.  `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you, this was it, the locale was different. Thank you